# Unable to see the request body in the console when using Postman

Tags: express, postman, body-parser

Since the last Postman update, I'm unable to get the response data in the console, from the request body that I'm sending to the endpoint.

Here's the code:

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('OK');
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('App is listening! :)'));
```

Then I make a `POST` request using Postman putting data in the Body part, On the log I get `"{}"`.

I have tested with `cURL`, and it works, that's why I suspect it is a problem with Postman.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: In postman, did you set the type to JSON? https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests#raw

Comment: It has always worked with form-data

Comment: It doesn't work with extended false, even when I comment the entire line leaving bodyParser.json() as the only middleware

Comment: What's actually happening in Postman? Can you update the question with an image of the error?

Comment: Running version 5.5.2 of the native app. I don't see anything wrong with this code when using Postman, Whatever i'm sending in the body of the `POST` is logged to the console and `OK` is returned in the response. Your issue seems to have nothing to do with Postman.

Comment: Yes this works for me too, what doesn't work is the value I log on the 10th line: req.body is empty when using Postman

Comment: I see the data from all of my requests logged to the console where the app is running. With details like...'It doesn't work' - this really isn't a question that people can answer. You have shown the app code and that's it, nothing about the request you're sending or the response you're getting from Postman. You need to update the question with more details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164623/discussion-between-danny-dainton-and-xobtah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code from the question, I am able to see the request body logged out to the console. This is using either the `raw > application/json` option or the `x-www-form-urlencoded` option the send the request.

[image: Postman_01]

In order to see data from the `form-data` option in Postman, I needed to add the [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) module to the code.

```
let express = require('express');
let multer = require('multer');
let upload = multer();
let app = express();

let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', upload.array(), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('OK');
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('App is listening! :)'));
```

As you can see from the image below, this is writing the request body to the console.

[image: Postman_02]